# Install armadillo in centos

Tags: linux, armadillo

I want to install armadillo on centos 6.4, but when i try to install it i face some problem like

```
[yemane@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install libarmadillo-dev

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
  * base: centos.tt.co.kr
  * extras: centos.tt.co.kr
  * updates: centos.tt.co.kr
Setting up Install Process
No package libarmadillo-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: enable the EPEL repo in CentOS, and then do "yum search armadillo". Alternatively, just install Armadillo manually.

Comment: mtall thanks for your responce .I was enable the EPEL repo and I was try to install,but it was the same can you tell me pls how can install armadillo manually in centos 6.4

Comment: see the README.txt file that is inside the Armadillo .tar.gz archive

Comment: ok thanks i will see it

Comment: Thank you mtall  it is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo yum install armadillo-devel
```

Comment: this gives me: No package armadillo-devel available.